# Read and filter a directory of parquet files on R / Python from S3 bucket

Tags: python, r, amazon-s3, databricks, parquet

I have some parquet files that I want to read and filter for a particular ID. The parquet files for each date is stored in seperate folders on S3 bucket. I want to read all the files in the bucket for a given date and filter it for a specific ID and construct a dataframe. I tried using Arrow package, but due to the file size, I am running out of error. Are there any alternate ways to approach this in R / Python / Databricks ? Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Build some small files and put them where anybody can download them. Then show some code that people can use. Otherwise this is just a package recommendation request which would make it off-topic on SO

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test without data but this might work: basically, these are some helper functions on top of the arrow package https://github.com/mkparkin/Rinvent . I use it a lot when I work on local windows machines

```
readparquetR(pathtoread="s3path/subdirectory/", filelocation = "s3", format="parquet", where="filter that you want to apply")
```

where condition goes into data.table filter part. i.e.
my_df = my_dt["filter that you want to apply",]

it reads all parquet files with lapply and filter each of them based on the where condition